# Entity Framework added to references but DbContext is not found

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I added Entity Framework to references but I still get an error that it does not exist .

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have very little information about your project settings, but it seems that you are using .Net Core. In order to use EntityFramework in .Net Core you need to follow these steps:

**.Net Core:**

You need to install [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/3.1.7?_src=template) package instead of `EntityFramework`. You can install this package via nuget using: `Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 3.1.7` (You might replace 3.1.7 with other versions if needed)

After installing the package you need to add `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` to you usings list or just replcae `DbContext` with `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext`

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
namespace FriendOrganizer.DataAccess{
     public class FriendOrganizerDbContext: DbContext{
     ...
     }
}
```

Or

```
namespace FriendOrganizer.DataAccess{
     public class FriendOrganizerDbContext: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext{
     ...
     }
}
```

However if you want to use ENtityFramework in .Net Framework you should follow these steps instead:

**.Net Framework**

You need to install [EntityFramework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/) package. You can install it via nuget using: `Install-Package EntityFramework -Version 6.4.4` (You might replace 6.4.4 with other versions if needed),

After installing the package you need to add `System.Data.Entity` to your `using`s list or just replace the `DbContext` with `System.Data.Entity.DbContext`

```
using System.Data.Entity;
namespace FriendOrganizer.DataAccess{
     public class FriendOrganizerDbContext: DbContext{
     ...
     }
}
```

Or

```
namespace FriendOrganizer.DataAccess{
     public class FriendOrganizerDbContext: System.Data.Entity.DbContext{
     ...
     }
}
```

Comment: I did it , the problem is that "System.Data.Entity" doesn't exist @Vahid

Comment: @MohamedOueslati are you using .Net Core bro?

Comment: @MohamedOueslati would you please show us your .csproj file content or your project properties screen?

Comment: I checked again and found that there is .Net core by default , that what caused the problem , and I resolved it . Thank you for your help Mr @Vahid

Comment: @MohamedOueslati Great bro. It would be even greater if you mark my post as answer and upvoted it, if you found it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think this issue is from the Pluralsight video: Building an Enterprise App with WPF, MVVM, and Entity Framework Code First.

At Section 5, in the area titled:  Create a DbContext Subclass, the author (T. Huber) - installs the Entity Framework 6.1.3 (not the core version) - from NuGet.  When I did this, I grabbed version 6.4.4.  After doing that, using System.Data.Entity; did not work.   I would get:

"CS0234: The type or namespace 'Entity' does not exist in he namespace 'System.Data' (are you missing an assembly reference?)" Later I tried EF Core, only to find the base("FriendOrganizerDb") doesn't like that string in there.

My solution was to uninstall the Nuget packages, and Install NuGet Entity Framework ver 6.1.3 as per the video.  That "version" of Entity Framework works with:  using System.Data.Entity;

Comment: your problem is the same as mine and it was in the course you mentioned , I found that the project was not targetting .net Framework , it was targetting .net Standard , please check thar when you create you project FriendOrganizer.DataAccess

Comment: Thank you - I stumbled over this later in the course at "Enable-Migrations" -  YES, I made my DataAcess project of .net Standard,  not .net Framework.   I re-did the DataAccess project of that type - and now things are working (for now).  Thanks for your comment - it saved me time.